# Can you retrieve index of all files when connecting to a webserver

Tags: java, web, web-crawler

is it possible to retrieve a index of all files on the web server when connecting to a website?
(Something similar to this image: http://www.linuxscrew.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/06/directory_index.png)

I understand that you can achieve similar effect using a web crawler, but there might be some unlisted links on the website, that are public, but invisible. Is there any way to access those files?

Comment: It depends if the web server allows directory browsing/listing.

Answer (score 0):

Not unless the server is configured to expose such a list. In many cases, there are very few "files", per se, in the first place. Resources are database records that are processed by server-side routines to provide HTML content to the browser.